# Programmatically detect if a web page has embedded a youtube video

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

Is it possible to programmatically detect if a web page has embedded a youtube video? If yes, please give me some direction on how to write the codes.

I am thinking my function should fetch the URL, then examine all elements in the dom (this is the part I doubt if possible). Then fetch that youtube link (if found) to see if it's a valid video. Is my flow correct? Is there a simpler/easier implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: In pure JS you can't do that as you can not access the dom of the external page.

Comment: Thanks @ErikS , how about other languages (combination)?

Comment: What language do you know?

Comment: I don't know any languages. (´ヮ`)

Comment: But I found that I can use URLFetchApp.fetch in Google Apps Script to get the whole dom, then I can use some RegEx to get the embedded YouTube URL.

Comment: Yes you can check fro short and long urls in teh html